# Call a remote javascript function

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

by using phantomjs and or casperjs, is it posible to execute a javascript function that defined on the remote site ?

all i see in the docs is only to call builtin function in phantomjs and casperjs
is there anyway to do this with phantomjs and or casperjs ?

Answer (score 3):

Use its code evaluation feature (see the [documentation](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Page-Automation) for more details), e.g:

```
page.evaluate(function () {
    // do whatever you want, including calling any function
});
```

Comment: There is a concrete example in this blog article on webscraping with casperjs - http://www.subelsky.com/2012/08/webscraping-with-casperjs-and-phantomjs.html

Answer (score 0):

2 years later I stumbled upon the same problem. Here is the solution you were looking for.

```
page.evaluateJavaScript(function(){
  javascriptFunction();
});
```